# How can I display Quicktime's "New Movie Recording" function in ASCII

Tags: quicktime, webcam

I wonder if anyone could master this one?

So Quicktime can play movies in ASCII mode as per the link below:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ASCIIMoviePlayerSample/Introduction/Intro.html

But is it possible to view, through the webcam in Quicktime, the webcam video as ASCII art?

Answer (score 1):

Try [ASCII Projektor](http://earthlingsoft.net/ASCII%20Projektor/)

> … computer’s camera as well as from QuickTime files. …